# cannot be null - PhP PDO Function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a problem with one function, function should be sent a text to base (phpmyadmin), or menu displays error..

Error code:

> Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'Code' cannot be null

My function:

```
public function UploadInvoice($CONN)
{
  $SubmitOK = '1';
  $Core = new Core();
  $Core->CheckForEmpty(array('Code'), 'finances.php');

  if($SubmitOK == '1') {
    try {
      $SQL = 'INSERT INTO Invoices (UserID, Code) VALUES (:UserID, :Code)';
      $SQL = $CONN->prepare($SQL);
      $SQL->execute(array('UserID' => $_SESSION['UserLogin']['ID'], 'Code' => $Code));
      $_SESSION['Success'] = 'Successfully submitted your code, Wait for checking multiple payments, your money will be soon on the bill';
      header('location: finances');
      exit();
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
       echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
  } else {
      $_SESSION['Error'] = 'An error has occurred. Try again!';
      header('location: finances');
      exit();
  }
}
```

My form code:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required="true" minlength="4" name="Code" placeholder="Your ID">
    <button type="submit">SEND</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The error clearly states that `$Code` have no value

Comment: HI @CyberFX: You Didn't Respond To The Answer Given Below.

Answer (score 1):

You Missed "`:`" in `$SQL->execute...`. Append it with `UserID` & `Code`.

Change

```
$SQL->execute(array('UserID' => $_SESSION['UserLogin']['ID'], 'Code' => $Code));
```

To

```
$SQL->execute(array(':UserID' => $_SESSION['UserLogin']['ID'], ':Code' => $Code));
```

For More info, Please click [PDO Statement Execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)